# ionic slider ion-slide-box with width smaller than page width

Tags: ionic-framework

is there a way to display several slides at once with the ionic slider (ion-slide-box) ?

Can you help me achive a slider like this one :

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use **ion-slides**, it uses **Swiper API** and introduced in **ionic v1.2.0.**

[ion-slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/)

[Ionic Slides in ionic v2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/)

[Swiper Demos](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.V6YOvOt97IU)

Answer (score -3):

ion-slide-box works without any additional CSS. Just ionic.css. Have used it in my app. but as far as I see, it seems to be meant to only show one slide per page. Are you trying to modify CSS and get multiple slides to display per page? If so, I guess that's not the right approach.

This is the description given by Ionic for the ion-slide-box

**The Slide Box is a multi-page container where each page can be swiped or dragged between:**

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/